# How to animate this project

Tags: animate

I'm Brazilian, 18 years old and I have a final project in the first half in my university. I found here a code of one analog clock and I made a modification to create a speedometer. I wonder how I can animate with autoplay.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\foreach \hdeg / \mdeg in {0/0,2/30,4/60,6/90,8/120,10/150,12/180,14/210,
16/240}{ % pontos do mínimo ao máximo de rotação


\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line width=3pt]

\filldraw [fill=white!30] (0,0) circle (2cm); % cor e tamanho do círculo

\foreach \angle / \label in
{0/140, 30/120, 60/100, 90/80, 120/60, 150/40, 180/20,
210/0, 330/160} % Kilômetros
{
\draw[line width=2pt] (\angle:1.7cm) -- (\angle:2cm); % grossura e ângulo dos tracinhos dos KM's
\draw (\angle:1.4cm) node{\textsf{\label}};
}

\foreach \angle / \label in
{15/, 45/, 75/, 105/, 135/, 165/, 195/,345/, 270/SENAC-SP} % traços dos KM's sem número
{
\draw[line width=1pt] (\angle:1.8cm) -- (\angle:2cm);
\draw (\angle:1.4cm) node{\textsf{\label}};
}
\foreach \angle in {0,90,180,270}
\draw[line width=2pt] (\angle:2cm) -- (\angle:2cm);

\node[draw=none,font=\tiny,text=red] at (0,0.3cm) {Velocimetro PI - 1}; %texto

\draw[rotate=210,line width=1.5pt] (0,0) -- (-\mdeg:1cm); % ponteiro

\path [fill=red] (0,0) circle (3pt); % borda do círculo do ponteiro

\path [fill=white] (0,0) circle (2pt); % círculo do ponteiro

\end{tikzpicture}

}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a possible solution where `animationinline` is used from `animate` package. Please copy and paste, then compile to see the animation. Basically, one wraps the `tikzpicture` in an `animationinline` environment as shown below. Here `controls` means push bottoms are shown while `autoplay` won't have push bottoms. {10} means frames per section. `imedeg` is an integer variable; for real variables one uses `rxxx` for example. 0+1 means start counting from 0, 1, 2,... while 1+1 means start counting from 1,2,3,...

```
\begin{animateinline}[poster=first,controls]{10}
\multiframe{9}{imdeg=0+1}
{
tikzpicture environment where \imdeg is the counter
}
\end{animationinline}
```

Addendum: a second method is addressed.

```
\multido{\imdeg=0+1}{9}                              
{    
\begin{preview}
tikzpicture environment where \imdeg is the counter
\end{preview}
}
```

[image]

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[poster=first,controls]{10}
\multiframe{9}{imdeg=0+1}
%\foreach \hdeg / \mdeg in {0/0,2/30,4/60,6/90,8/120,10/150,12/180,14/210,16/240}
{ % pontos do mínimo ao máximo de rotação
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line width=3pt]
\filldraw [fill=white!30] (0,0) circle (2cm); % cor e tamanho do círculo
\foreach \angle / \label in
{0/140, 30/120, 60/100, 90/80, 120/60, 150/40, 180/20,
210/0, 330/160} % Kilômetros
{
\draw[line width=2pt] (\angle:1.7cm) -- (\angle:2cm); % grossura e ângulo dos tracinhos dos KM's
\draw (\angle:1.4cm) node{\textsf{\label}};
}
\foreach \angle / \label in
{15/, 45/, 75/, 105/, 135/, 165/, 195/,345/, 270/SENAC-SP} % traços dos KM's sem número
{\draw[line width=1pt] (\angle:1.8cm) -- (\angle:2cm);
\draw (\angle:1.4cm) node{\textsf{\label}};
}
\foreach \angle in {0,90,180,270}
\draw[line width=2pt] (\angle:2cm) -- (\angle:2cm);
\node[draw=none,font=\tiny,text=red] at (0,0.3cm) {Velocimetro PI - 1}; %texto
\draw[rotate=210,line width=1.5pt] (0,0) -- (-\imdeg*30:1cm); % ponteiro%%%
\path [fill=red] (0,0) circle (3pt); % borda do círculo do ponteiro
\path [fill=white] (0,0) circle (2pt); % círculo do ponteiro
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:** A second approach is use of `multido` package with `preview`.

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}%[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}

\begin{document}
\multido{\imdeg=0+1}{9}                              
%\foreach \hdeg / \mdeg in {0/0,2/30,4/60,6/90,8/120,10/150,12/180,14/210,16/240}
{ % pontos do mínimo ao máximo de rotação
\begin{preview}                                         
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line width=3pt]
\filldraw [fill=white!30] (0,0) circle (2cm); % cor e tamanho do círculo
\foreach \angle / \label in
{0/140, 30/120, 60/100, 90/80, 120/60, 150/40, 180/20,
210/0, 330/160} % Kilômetros
{
\draw[line width=2pt] (\angle:1.7cm) -- (\angle:2cm); % grossura e ângulo dos tracinhos dos KM's
\draw (\angle:1.4cm) node{\textsf{\label}};
}
\foreach \angle / \label in
{15/, 45/, 75/, 105/, 135/, 165/, 195/,345/, 270/SENAC-SP} % traços dos KM's sem número
{\draw[line width=1pt] (\angle:1.8cm) -- (\angle:2cm);
\draw (\angle:1.4cm) node{\textsf{\label}};
}
\foreach \angle in {0,90,180,270}
\draw[line width=2pt] (\angle:2cm) -- (\angle:2cm);
\node[draw=none,font=\tiny,text=red] at (0,0.3cm) {Velocimetro PI - 1}; %texto
\draw[rotate=210,line width=1.5pt] (0,0) -- (-{\imdeg*30}:1cm); % ponteiro%%%
\path [fill=red] (0,0) circle (3pt); % borda do círculo do ponteiro
\path [fill=white] (0,0) circle (2pt); % círculo do ponteiro
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{preview}                                           
}
\end{document}
```